# Azure Powershell secure secret value

Tags: azure, powershell, devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault

I am facing a weird issue and I don't have any idea why it is not working. I looked in all the documentation and tried different solution but nothing.

I am trying to script in powershelgl a simple command that takes 2 value:

- secret name
- secret value

I would like to have the `value` secured during the powershell execution, and when the script is finish, to see those parameters stored in a azure KeyVault -> Secrets.

I have set this code:

```
$SecretName = Read-Host "Enter Secret Name"
$password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
$password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password)
$password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringBSTR($password)

Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "keyvaultname" -Name $SecretName -SecretValue $password
```

But this it gives me the following error:

```
Cannot bind parameter 'SecretValue'. Cannot convert the "asdlkjiou" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".
```

Notice: I am converting back the password because if I don't do so, the code runs, but the value in the KeyVault is showed as follow `System.Security.SecureString`

I am pretty much lost here, haven't used Windows PowerShell in a long time and none of the solution or documentation I found helped me to solve this problem.

Please, if anyone can direct me on how I can achieve this, I would be grateful.

And please if you need more infos, don't hesitate to ask me

Comment: How you check that the value in Azure KeyVault is `System.Security.SecureString`?

Comment: In azure portal I check the value of the secret

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to perform those conversions with the `InteropServices` calls. Just use these three lines. The `password` variable is already of the correct type since you're reading it `-AsSecureString`.

```
$SecretName = Read-Host "Enter Secret Name"
$password = Read-Host "Enter password" -AsSecureString
Set-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName 'keyvaultname' -Name $SecretName -SecretValue $password
```